# How can I see what libraries Mingw32 links by default?

Tags: c++, windows, mingw32

I'm using Mingw32 compiler to build a C++ app.

I'm passing -nostdlib to the linker because I only want to link the libraries I'm going to actually use.

However I'm running into a problem with the C++ standard library.

When I link with libstdc++ I get the following error:
undefined reference to '_Unwind_SjLj_Register'

So clearly libstdc++ isn't the right library to link with.

Is there any way of seeing what libraries Mingw32 links with by default when building a C++ app?

**What libraries are being excluded when the flag -nostdlib is passed to linker?**

Thanks.

Comment: `Mingw32` is a shell, are you using the `g++` compiler included with the package? If so, you can use one of the `-print-X` flags (do `g++ --help` to see the list of `print-X` flags)